# Toggle expand when over 900px toggle collapse when under 900px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I want this to be expanded when I am on a screen that has more than 900px(min-width: 901px;) and when I am on a screen that has less than 900px (max-width; 900px) I want it to be closed so that I can manually click on it and so that it will be expanded.

This is the code that I have for the div to expand when I click on it

```
$('.exp_collapsed').click(function(){
    $('.text_ads_expand_button_mer_info').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

the .text_ads_expand_button_mer_info is the text that I want user to be able to click on and when they do it will expand.

am I changing this in the jquery or in the css ?

Comment: I see no attempt to get the screen width in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(window).width()>900){ // Window width > 900
 // Show .expand_me 
 $(".expand_me").fadeIn();
}
else{
// Hide .expand_me 
$(".expand_me").fadeOut();
}
});
```

```css
.expand_me{
min-width:25px;
 min-height:25px;
  background:#f00000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='expand_me'></div>
```